# Yii Bootstrap Model Window Open on load

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I'm currently using Twitter bootstrap for Yii (http://www.cniska.net/yii-bootstrap/#tbModal)

The modal window displayed on their site opens when clicked on a button. Anyone has any clues on how to open the modal window on page load?

I tried simulation a button click in javascript on load, but that's not really the correct way to go

Comment: how about the `autoOpen` option..

Comment: Yep, that was it... If you put it as an answer I will accept it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try the option `autoOpen` as documented on http://www.cniska.net/yii-bootstrap/#tbModal